# Unable to get login screen on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, nvidia, 17.10

Botched upgrade is giving me a black screen instead of the login menu. If I boot into recovery mode and start that way, the following blinks on the screen:

[image]

How can I fix the system? I have 4.13 low latency, 4.13 normal, 4.10 normal kernel installed and NVIDIA 384.90 drivers as well for 780 Ti.

Answer (score 0):

Unstalling gdm, which refused to work, and installing lightdm instead worked.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had this problem after upgrading my laptop from 16.04 to 17.10, and the problem was that ubuntu-desktop wasn't installed.  Installing that fixed the login cycling problem for me.